# Failing to array_merge(), same output prior to loop

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I've seen numerous related questions, none answered this for me - I apologize if that's due to my lack of knowledge...

I have an array, `$contacts`, where each record looks like the below, with 1-many contacts:

```
[{internal_id}]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(13) "matching name"
      ["bphone"]=>
      string(13) "(123)345-5678"
      ["cphone"]=>
      string(13) "(321)345-6857"
      ["hphone"]=>
      string(13) "(123)543-5790"
      ["email"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["email2"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    [1]=>
    array(6) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(13) "matching name"
      ["bphone"]=>
      string(13) "(123)345-5678"
      ["cphone"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["hphone"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["email"]=>
      string(20) "margethis@please.com"
      ["email2"]=>
      string(21) "mergethis2@please.com"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(6) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(17) "not matching name"
      ["bphone"]=>
      string(13) "(123)987-6453"
      ["cphone"]=>
      string(13) "(321)789-3546"
      ["hphone"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["email"]=>
      string(21) "email@popularmail.com"
      ["email2"]=>
      string(22) "email2@popularmail.com"
    }
  }
```

I want to combine any like names, per record, keeping the relevant contact info. Trying this:

```
    $i = 1; //1 > 0 so no need to +1 each time it's used in this case
    foreach($contacts as $contact){
        if($contact['name'] == $contacts[$i]['name']){
            $contact = array_merge($contact, $contacts[$i]);
            unset($contacts[$i]);
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

My expected/desired output would be:

```
[{internal_id}]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(13) "matching name"
      ["bphone"]=>
      string(13) "(123)345-5678"
      ["cphone"]=>
      string(13) "(321)345-6857"
      ["hphone"]=>
      string(13) "(123)543-5790"
      ["email"]=>
      string(20) "margethis@please.com"
      ["email2"]=>
      string(21) "mergethis2@please.com"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(6) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(17) "not matching name"
      ["bphone"]=>
      string(13) "(123)987-6453"
      ["cphone"]=>
      string(13) "(321)789-3546"
      ["hphone"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["email"]=>
      string(21) "email@popularmail.com"
      ["email2"]=>
      string(22) "email2@popularmail.com"
    }
  }
```

But the loop isn't having any effect, at least not that I can find. My actual output matches the initial array.

What am I missing here?

EDIT/UPDATE: Simple mix up on passing by reference/value. Thanks @Barmar for the quick solution. No changes were reflected in the array because I never actually told php to update those values. Shocking how that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two reasons why your code doesn't work:

1. Assigning to `$contact` doesn't change the array, it just reassigns the variable.
2. `array_merge()` doesn't modify the array in place, it returns a new array.

You can solve both problems by making `$contact` a reference variable.

```
foreach ($contacts as &$contact) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think I've said it before, but thanks for all your answers in php on here. See your responses a lot. Seems obvious once you point it out...

Comment: It's call by value vs. call by `&` reference.